# arrays. getting the 3rd item of this multi array

Tags: php

Please help. I want to print the price. I need to print the price only. Help me. Thanks

```
  $x=array(array('itm_name'=>'Optimization','price'=>'100','desc'=>'Chuchu'));
```

Comment: `echo $x[0]['price'];`

Comment: what if it looks like this? $x=array(array('itm_name'=>'Optimization','price'=>'100','desc'=>'Chuchu','itm_name'=>'Computer Setup','price'=>'200','desc'=>'Chacha'));

Comment: It can't look like that. An array cannot have 2 keys that are the same. That is an invalid array

Comment: It could look like -> `$x=array(array('itm_name'=>'Optimization','price'=>'100','desc'=>'Chuchu'), array ('itm_n‌​ame'=>'Computer Setup','price'=>'200','desc'=>'Chacha'));`, which you could then do -> `foreach($x as $y){ echo $y['price']; }`

Comment: my fault. consider this one. $x=array(array('itm_name'=>'Optimization','price'=>'100','desc'=>'Chuchu'),array('itm_n‌​ame'=>'Computer Setup','price'=>'200','desc'=>'Chacha'));

Comment: Do you need just the price of the *first* element or the price for *each* element? Please edit the question with these code samples and explain better.

Comment: That is where you would do `foreach($x as $y){ echo $y['price']."<br />"; }` if you want all `price` values, or `echo $x[0]['price'];`/`echo $x[1]['price'];` if you want a specific `price`

Comment: $x=array(array('itm_name'=>'Optimization','price'=>'100','desc'=>'Chuchu'),array‌​('itm_n‌​ame'=>'Computer Setup','price'=>'200','desc'=>'Chacha')); im get this from my shopping cart. What i need is the value of price to be inserted to the database with different id. Can someone help me? Did anyone get my question?

Comment: You could use the outer array key as the `id` -> `foreach($x as $id => $y){ INSERT INTO yourTable (id, price) VALUES ($id, $y['price']; }`

Comment: please ignore. thanks.

Comment: (You can delete comments here Jalo, and it is encouraged for comments that are no longer useful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using a 2 dimensional array

have you tried

```
echo $x[0]['price']
```

note '0' is the first element of the 1st layer of the array

so this can be substituted with 'x' so can iterate through a list

additionally if you want to get the other items of the array then

```
echo $x[0]['itm_name']
```

i hope you have grasped the basic concept of multi-dimensional arrays
using this simple explanation

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$x[0]['price']
```

`$x[0]` means the first element of the outer array, and `['price']` gets the `price` element of the inner array.